# Firebase fetches whole parents data, even when there is no valid path, How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am fetching data from firebase using ref(). The issue , i am facing is when there is no valid child path means, its fetching whole parent. For example, when i need to fetch something from ('User/'+phone), it works correctly when the phone is provided, But when there is no data in phone, then it goes to parent to fetch all.

I am using this, using redux and thunk. So the firebase values are fetched by the actions

Here is my Firebase Code in actions !:

```
 export const fetchOrderHistory = (phone, callback) => {
 return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: START_SPINNER_ACTION_FOR_ORDER_HISTORY })
    firebase.database().ref('orders/'+phone)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
        const snapShotValue = snapshot.val();
        callback(snapShotValue);
        dispatch ({ type: ORDER_HISTORY_FETCHED , payload: snapshot.val()});
        dispatch({ type: STOP_SPINNER_ACTION_FRO_ORDER_HISTORY })
    });

};
```

};

Kindly help !

Comment: That's the way Realtime Database queries work.  Not sure what you're hoping it would do differently.

Comment: ('orders/'+phone) when the value of phone is " " in this, will the system neglects the empty string and fetch from orders ?

Comment: You expect it to do something different? That sounds like a case you should be checking in your own code.

Comment: What you can do is first fetch the whole parent data, then check if it has the child that is required with datasnapshot.hasChild(<phone>) and then only fetch required data.

Comment: okay guys, thanks for all ! will see whats can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the logic

```
firebase.database().ref('orders/'+ phone)
```

First of all, the word `phone` here is a variable, you could put x, and its value will be passed to firebase, like this

```
firebase.database().ref('orders/'+ x)
```

If `x` = 'phone' then this mean you are asking firebase to get you

```
  firebase.database().ref('orders/phone')
```

If x = 'users', this means you are asking firebase to get you this

```
  firebase.database().ref('orders/users')
```

If x = '', this means you are asking firebase to get you this

```
  firebase.database().ref('orders/')
```

Comment: Would be nice if you accepted this as your answer :)